# QThread crash when show QMessageBox PyQt5 Python

Tags: python, pyqt5, messagebox, qthread

**I'm trying to show MessageBox in QThread, but the program always crash after close the MessageBox.** I tried to find answer about "create QThread" and "create QMessageBox in another thread", but none of these solved my problem, and some answers are for PyQt4.

The whole code is from a simple tutorial : https://realpython.com/python-pyqt-qthread/

**I only insert some code under function reportProgress to raise an error and show a messagebox.**

Please teach me how to code the messagebox part, I already tried to solve this for days, really appreciate.

```
# Code from: https://realpython.com/python-pyqt-qthread/
import sys
from time import sleep
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QThread, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QLabel,
    QMainWindow,
    QPushButton,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
    QMessageBox,
)

# Step 1: Create a worker class
class Worker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    progress = pyqtSignal(int)

    def run(self):
        """Long-running task."""
        for i in range(5):
            sleep(1)
            self.progress.emit(i + 1)
        self.finished.emit()

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.clicksCount = 0
        self.setupUi()

    def setupUi(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Freezing GUI")
        self.resize(300, 150)
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        # Create and connect widgets
        self.clicksLabel = QLabel("Counting: 0 clicks", self)
        self.clicksLabel.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.stepLabel = QLabel("Long-Running Step: 0")
        self.stepLabel.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.countBtn = QPushButton("Click me!", self)
        self.countBtn.clicked.connect(self.countClicks)
        self.longRunningBtn = QPushButton("Long-Running Task!", self)
        self.longRunningBtn.clicked.connect(self.runLongTask)
        # Set the layout
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.clicksLabel)
        layout.addWidget(self.countBtn)
        layout.addStretch()
        layout.addWidget(self.stepLabel)
        layout.addWidget(self.longRunningBtn)
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(layout)

    def countClicks(self):
        self.clicksCount += 1
        self.clicksLabel.setText(f"Counting: {self.clicksCount} clicks")

    def reportProgress(self, n):
        self.stepLabel.setText(f"Long-Running Step: {n}")
        # I insert this, trying to show a messagebox when error occurs
        if n == 3:
            try:
                print(int('aaa'))
            except:
                QMessageBox.information(self, 'Warning', 'Success', QMessageBox.Ok)

    def runLongTask(self):
        # Step 2: Create a QThread object
        self.thread = QThread()
        # Step 3: Create a worker object
        self.worker = Worker()
        # Step 4: Move worker to the thread
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        # Step 5: Connect signals and slots
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.worker.deleteLater)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread.deleteLater)

        self.worker.progress.connect(self.reportProgress)
        # Step 6: Start the thread
        self.thread.start()

        # Final resets
        self.longRunningBtn.setEnabled(False)
        self.thread.finished.connect(
            lambda: self.longRunningBtn.setEnabled(True)
        )
        self.thread.finished.connect(
            lambda: self.stepLabel.setText("Long-Running Step: 0")
        )

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = Window()
win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This seems to be caused by a bug in PyQt5/6. The same code does not segfault with PySide2. A work-around is to decorate `run` and/or `reportProgress` with `@pyqtSlot`.

Answer (score 0):

The code works as-is for me, no crashing. It could be a problem with the version of python you are running or the version of PyQt5 you have installed - I suggest updating everything.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the program will crash after you click ok on your message box. to only raised a message box you only need to change

```
try:
            print(int('aaa'))
        except:
            QMessageBox.information(self, 'Warning', 'Success', QMessageBox.Ok)
```

become

```
try:
   print(int('aaa'))
except:
   print("no error")
finally:
   QMessageBox.information(
                self, 'Warning', 'Success', QMessageBox.Ok)
```